# Inner product defined on the vector space of continuous real-valued functions and definiteness property

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook linear algebra done right (pg166) defines the inner product on a continuous real-valued function as

[image]

I am not sure how I would verify definiteness, defined as $\langle v, v \rangle = 0 ~IFF~ v = 0$

In the example, if $f=g=0$, how do you evaluate $\int_{-1}^{1} 0dx = 0$? Is there a property I am overlooking that says this is true for integration?

Comment: The integral of zero is definitely zero.  There are any number of ways to see this, depending on what definitions you want to start from.  How much calculus do you know? The harder part is the "only if" - that the *only* nonnegative function with an integral of zero, is the zero function.

Comment: I am in my first semester of Multivariate calculus so I am okay with continuity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Note that $(f(x))^2\geq 0$, $ \forall x\in[-1,1]$. Then $$\langle f, f \rangle = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \int_{[-1,1]}f(x)f(x)dx=0 $$

and

$\int_{[-1,1]}(f(x))^2dx=0$$\Leftrightarrow(f(x))^2=0,\forall x\in[-1,1] \Leftrightarrow f(x)=0, \forall x\in[-1,1]$

Otherwise, there is $ x_0\in[-1,1] $ such that $ f(x_0) > 0$ and by the continuity of $ f $ in $ x_0 $ there would be $ U \subseteq [-1,1] $ open interval so that $ \int_{U} f(x) ^ 2dx> 0. $